# Removing all occurrences of a character from string without replace method

Tags: java

I need to write a method called `remove()` that takes two arguments, a `String` and a `char`, and returns a new String that removes all occurrences of the char from the input String. I have to do this without using the `replace()` method. So far I have:

```
public class Remover
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String sampleString = "this is some text";
        char sampleChar = 's';
        System.out.print(remove(sampleString, sampleChar));
    }
    public static String remove(String a, char b)
    {
      String newString = "";
        newString = a.substring(0, a.indexOf(b))+""+a.substring(a.indexOf(b)+1);

        return newString;
    }
}
```

The main method is just there for testing purposes and the sample string and char are just examples; I need this method to work for any string and char. But either way, I'm sure what I have is wrong and I'm completely lost on how to proceed. For this case, I'm trying to get my code to return

```
"thi i ome text"
```

Comment: Yes, what you have is wrong. Think about what you're effectively trying to do: look over all the characters in the string, copying the ones which *aren't* the character to remove. Hint: look at `StringBuilder` and `String.charAt`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Get `char` array from the string using `string.toCharArray()` method.
2. Traverse the `char` array. Append the `char` to a String if it is not equal to your target `char`
3. Use [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class for appending: building the string.

Comment: Don't suggest an alternative solution, try to fix this one and advise to improve with your solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The problem is doing such operation with `substring` seems quite less than sense to me. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the String using `charAt()`

```
String s = "this is some text";

public static String remove(String a, char b) {

    String word = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++){
        if (s.charAt(i) != b){
            word += a.charAt(i);
        }
    }

    return word;

}
```

An alternative to String concatenating is to use `StringBuilder` inside the loop

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++){
    if (s.charAt(i) != b){
        sb.append(s.charAt(i));
    }
}

return sb.toString();
```

Another way to approach this is to convert the String to a char array and traverse the array

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder;

 for (char c : s.toCharArray()){
     if (c != b) {
         sb.append(c);
     }   
 }

 return word;
```

Comment: It works, and it seems pretty simple too. Iteration was something I mulled over for awhile but wasn't sure how I would implement it.

Answer (score 0):

**I'll not suggest an alternative solution**, I'll tell you how to fix the problem in **your current** code.

Your program works only for the first occurrence of `s`. You should do the following:

1. Split the string according to `" "`.
2. Pass each word in the array to `remove` method.
3. Print the result on the same line with `" "`.

Should have something like that:

```
String sampleString = "this is some text";
String[] arr = sampleString.split(" ");
char sampleChar = 's';
for(String str : arr) {
    System.out.print(remove(str, sampleChar) + " ");
}
```

Note that in `remove` method, you should check if the String contains `s`, if not, return it as it is:

```
public static String remove(String a, char b) {
   if(!a.contains(b)) {
      return a;
   }
   String newString = "";
   newString = a.substring(0, a.indexOf(b))+""+a.substring(a.indexOf(b)+1);
   return newString;
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion like below.  But still use StringBuilder,that s the better way. This is just to make your code work

```
public static String remove(String a, char b)
{
   String newString = "";
   newString = a.substring(0, a.indexOf(b))+""+a.substring(a.indexOf(b)+1);
   if(newString.indexOf(b)!=-1) {
     newString= remove(newString,b);
   }
   return newString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the source string to char array using `a.toCharArray())`,

then write a for-loop to compare the char element in char array one-by-one with expected removed char.

If it is not equal, then append it to StringBuilder object.

have a try with this;

```
 public static String remove(String a, char b) {
    /*String newString = "";
    newString = a.substring(0, a.indexOf(b)) + ""
            + a.substring(a.indexOf(b) + 1);

    return newString;*/

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(char c: a.toCharArray())
    {
        if(c!= b)
        {
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: It works, but I have yet to reach StringBuilder as far as my (limited) Java experience goes. I'll be sure to keep this in mind in the future though.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class charReplace{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    String sampleString = "This is some text";
    char sampleChar = 's';
    System.out.println(char_remove(sampleString, sampleChar));
}

public static String char_remove(String a, char b){
    String newString = " ";
    int len = a.length();
    for(int i =0; i<len ;i++)
     {
       char c = a.charAt(i);
       if(c == b)
          newString = newString + " ";
       else
          newString = newString + c ;  
     }
    return newString;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer should contain an explanation of your code and a description how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static String remove(String a, char b)
    {
       StringBuilder sbul =new StringBuilder();
       int i;
        for(i=0;i<a.length();i++){
              char c = a.charAt(i);
               if(c==b)
                  continue;
                sbul.append(c);
             }
        return sbul.toString();
}
```